# Find Average from recent most data when there are multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

Hi I need to find out a way to find average on data set when there multiple values but consider a specific value based on recent most

```
 Table 1
 ColumnA  ColumnB   ColumnC
   A        3         07/21/2017
   A        2         08/08/2017
   B        1          07/22/2017
```

Calculate averae of ColumnB

It should 2 from A, 1 from B, which should be (2+1)/2 =1.5 and not (3+2+1)/3=2. The criteria is based on recent most time stamp of each category of columnA

Answer (score 1):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select avg(columnB * 1.0)
from  (select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by columnA order by columnC desc) as seqnum
       from t
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/daea4/3

```
Select 
   ColumnA, Avg(ColumnB)
from 
  table1
group by
  ColumnA
```